# CakePHP 3.0 not running on other machines

Tags: php, cakephp, namespaces, cakephp-3.0

I've developed a small project on a machine, using CakePHP 3.0, and I need it to run on another machine. I've tried to install it on several other machines.

If I run the `composer` to install the CakePHP 3.0, then I copy my stuff to overwrite it, the project works. I've tried this on two machines and had no problem so far. If I don't run the `composer`, and just copy the stuff to the target machine, it gives me the following error. I've tried this on 3 machines, and every machine gives me this:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in /home/u113681897/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/I18n.php on line 229

Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in /home/u113681897/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/I18n.php on line 229
```

I've copied the whole project to [this server](http://eburn.twomini.com/) to test.

I told you this because I thought it has something to do with my problem. The point is that I have to run this on a machine that is not mine, and I can't install composer on it. The `/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/` has files related to internationalization and localization, but my project will never be translated, so a workaround to make the project ignore those files would be enough to solve my problem.

The following code is an excerpt from the `(...)/I18n/I18n.php` that might be relevant:

```
<?php
namespace Cake\I18n;

use Aura\Intl\FormatterLocator;
use Aura\Intl\PackageLocator;
use Aura\Intl\TranslatorFactory;
use Cake\I18n\Formatter\IcuFormatter;
use Cake\I18n\Formatter\SprintfFormatter;
use Locale;

class I18n {

    // lots of code here

    public static function defaultLocale() {
        if (static::$_defaultLocale === null) {
            static::$_defaultLocale = Locale::getDefault() ?: 'en_US';
            // the line above is the Line 229
        }
        return static::$_defaultLocale;
    }

    // many code here too
}
```

I've checked that another file also tries to access this `Locale` class, but I don't know if there are other files trying to access it as well. Many files from everywhere inside the project tries to access methods from `I18n.php`. I need it running but I can't figure out how to make it run.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The web server that you are running on should support the intl extension. Perform a phpinfo(); in an empty file and run it to check if intl extension has been enabled.

Answer (score 0):

As I just found out, prior to `CakePHP 3.0`, the installation must be done by `composer`, as stated in the [3.0 migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html):

```
CakePHP should be installed with Composer

Since CakePHP can no longer easily be installed via PEAR, or in a shared
directory, those options are no longer supported. Instead you should use
Composer to install CakePHP into your application.
```

So it won't run on regular free web hosting services.

Comment: There is no need for composer being installed on the final production server, you only need it in your dev environment, then deploy the files to the production server and you're set. Whether the "regular free" (which often is equivalent to crappy, outdated, unprofessional) web hosting is able to run CakePHP, is a totally different question that has nothing to do with composer.

Comment: `Locale` is a class that ships with the [**PHP Intl extension**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php), and it should be available by default when using a proper web hosting provider, there are even crappy [**1.95$/mo plans**](http://mochahost.com/webhosting.php) that support it.

Comment: I have a desktop that I was using to test it, and I enabled PHP intl but it still gave me that error message. What else can it be? Or it's a bug maybe?