# cakephp-3.0 novice, \vendor\autoload.php

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am a cakePHP novice and am attempting to learn by examination of a working model.  So far I have downloaded two cakePHP 3 examples.   Both were missing a \vendor\autoload.php component.   Can anyone point me to a cakePHP 3 example that works "out of the box" without any additional setup required for the novice user ?

Comment: OK, I got past this point by using compose.phar to download cakephp 3.0.0.   (I had previously used the .zip file method.)  `  I am now hung up on "Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in \cake3\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\I18n\I18n.php on line 235.         line 235 is   static::$_defaultLocale = Locale::getDefault() ?: 'en_US';      I have not had any success in getting past this point.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493761/cakephp-3-0-not-running-on-other-machines | http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#requirements |  http://php.net/intl

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I am now operational, but it was a struggle.

Comment: Here is my path to success.  Determine that the .zip file download is not an operational system.  Download composer.phar and build complete cakephp 3 system, including /vendor directory. (packagist.org not responding so I had to alter /Windows/System32/drivers/etc/host, attrib -R then edit in Administrator mode to add "87.98.253.214 packagist.org") Now the composer.phar runs correctly.  Enable the php intl extension in php.ini and then recycle Apache server.  Copy app.default.php to app.php.  Success !!!

Answer (score 1):

For XAMPP needed changes in php.ini uncomment

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```